# Run chokidar commands conditionally

Tags: node.js, npm-scripts, chokidar

This is my first time with chokidar and I would like to know how to run chokidar commands conditionally from the npm scripts. I need to run run two different scripts, one on start and another on change. I have set chokidar-cli as one of my dev dependencies but cannot understand how to make it use two different commands at two different times.

Although there is not much code to share but the following I tried and it does not work even for the change:

```
"chokidar": "chokidar \"app.js\" -c \"if [ '{event}' = 'change' ]; then echo 'it changed'; fi;\"",
```

Comment: At that point, maybe start thinking about creating a file that requires chokidar and then write normal event filtered file watching code, then run _that_ as your node script instead (`"chokidar": "node util/watch-files.js"` or something)

Comment: How would  you do that in the event chokidar is required to decide whether the open flag on webpack-dev-server should be set or not?

Comment: chokidar is constant file monitoring, so if you need to change webpack flags, which only makes sense for webpack rebuilds, you'd make chokidar call your rebuild task with the appropriate environment variable. E.g. using https://github.com/mysticatea/npm-run-all/blob/HEAD/docs/node-api.md (and probably with https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env installed to make sure your env var works on windows, linux, and macos). I can turn that into an answer if you like with more concrete code examples.

Comment: Surely, would love you to go ahead. My purpose is to switch the dev-server open flag to off on rebuilds so as to prevent multiple tabs being opened on reload. My scenario is a bit different and you can also take a look at my project here: https://github.com/whimsicaldreamer/Html5-template/tree/v2.0.0 The project currently uses nodemon on but would be shifting to chokidar.

Comment: that sounds more like you want two separate npm scripts, one for running in production mode without reloading, and one for dev mode with reload? That's something that's already common practice in react land, and has a bunch of useful tutorials already.

Comment: Btw I would like to let you know that I need to call two scripts one on start and another on reload, while being in the same environment, i.e; development.

Comment: Well my project is not based on react/vue/angular. It's a very bland and simple project that uses plain old html, css, and js.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208866/discussion-between-ayan-and-mike-pomax-kamermans).